# Prompt dialog in JavaScript runs before the code written earlier

Tags: javascript

Why the prompt dialog in JavaScript runs before the code written earlier?
For example
It seems to me in this code the "main-heading" should be shown at first then for loop and only after that prompt dialogue?

```
<h1 id="main-heading">Hello World!!!</h1>
<script>
  var friends= ["Olya", "Dima", "Dan", "Dennis", "Sasha" ];
  for ( var r= 0, rmax= friends.length; r < rmax; r++ ) {
    $("body").append("<p>" + friends[r] + "</p>");  
    console.log('friends[r]', friends[r]);
  }         
  var newHeading= prompt("Enter NEW Heading");
  $("#main-heading").text(newHeading);
</script>
```

Comment: The code before `prompt` has run, but you can't see its effect, because the prompt box stopped page redrawing.

Comment: Also, [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/106031/211784) explains why using `prompt` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The body tag is not closed yet, so it cannot be rendered/painted.
You might want to wait to loading the content, by adding your code to a callback, that runs *after* the html had been rendered. With jQuery, its really easy to accomplish using [jQuery ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function(){
    //Everything is loaded, let's manipulate the body
});
```

Comment: [–1​ not enough jQuery](http://needsmorejquery.com/)